# While creating iceberg table in snowflake I am getting error like "Unified iceberg tables require a catalog integration to be specified"

Tags: amazon-s3, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, apache-iceberg

I am trying to setup iceberg table in snowflake by following the official [snowflake blog](https://www.snowflake.com/blog/iceberg-tables-powering-open-standards-with-snowflake-innovations/)

While I tried to create table using,

```
create or replace iceberg table my_iceberg_table_test
with EXTERNAL_VOLUME = 'my_ext_vol_test'
as select * from <MY_TABLE_NAME>;
```

I am getting error saying

> Unified iceberg tables require a catalog integration to be specified

I didn't find any prerequisite or step about catalog integration in snowflake official blog. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1):

If your company is part of the Preview then you should have access to the official docs as well rather than only the blog post.
Basically there are 3 steps involved in creating an Iceberg table with step 2 being optional based on how you want to have your Iceberg table managed.

So:

*Step 1. Create an external volume*

*Step 2. Create a catalog integration*

***Note:***
Skip this step if you plan to create an Iceberg table that uses Snowflake as the catalog. A catalog integration is required only when you want to create an Iceberg table that is not managed by Snowflake.

Example: Create a catalog integration for AWS Glue:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE CATALOG INTEGRATION glueCatalogInt
  CATALOG_SOURCE=GLUE
  CATALOG_NAMESPACE='icebergdb'
  TABLE_FORMAT=ICEBERG
  GLUE_CATALOG_ID='1234567890'
  GLUE_AWS_ROLE_ARN='arn:aws:iam::123:role/dummy-role'
  GLUE_REGION='us-west-2'
  ENABLED=TRUE;
```

*Step 3. Create an Iceberg table*